# Type Inference for a mixed in generic trait

Tags: scala, generics, type-inference

I am trying to create a Workflow Builder - a simplified version of my problem appears below.
The Scala Compiler seems to have trouble filling the type parameters in BuilderExtensions.
I am trying to get the compiler to infer Y by realising that ProducedComponent implements Produce[Y].
The only solutions I have got working require you to specify Y explicitly.
I have tried reading about type classes etc. but I am not well versed in this sort of theory. Is anyone able to help? It's driving me spare.

```
abstract class Component {}

trait Produce[+A <: Component] {
  def produce: A

}

case class ProducedComponent() extends Component

case class ProducerComponent()
    extends Component
    with Produce[ProducedComponent] {
  override def produce: ProducedComponent = ProducedComponent()
}

case class Builder[Result <: Component](w: Result) {}
object Extensions {
  implicit class BuilderExtension[Y <: Component,X <: Component with Produce[Y]](
      w: Builder[X]
  ) {
    def thenProduce(): Builder[Y] = {
      Builder(w.w.produce)
    }
  }
}
import Extensions._

val x = Builder(
  ProducerComponent()
)

import scala.reflect.runtime.universe
import universe.WeakTypeTag

def getType[A: WeakTypeTag](x: A) = universe.weakTypeOf[A]

getType(x)

// Does not Compile
val y = x.thenProduce()

getType(y)
```

Comment: Runtime reflection is not recommended

Comment: The runtime reflection was only for checking. I want the types to be checked at compile time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to modify `BuilderExtension`

```
implicit class BuilderExtension[X <: Component](
  w: Builder[X]
) {
  def thenProduce[Y <: Component]()(implicit ev: X <:< Produce[Y]): Builder[Y] = {
    Builder(w.w.produce)
  }
}
```